# Discord.py: My programm seems to be unable to differentiate between errors(MissingPerms, BotMissingPerms) and therefore uses the wrong handler

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, command, discord.py

I am trying to catch some errors that could be produced by users wrongly using a command.
To test this, I have created a command which raises errors on demand and a function that should catch them.
The Problem is, my attempt to catch `commands.BotMissingPermisions`, `commands.MissingPermissions` and `commands.CommandOnCooldown` seem to get ignored and handled as `commands.CommandInvokeError`. Other errors, for example `TooManyArguments` or `NotOwner` get catched just fine.

thats my Code:

```
Import discord
from discord.ext Import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~')

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send('missing perms')
  elif isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send('bot missing perms')
  elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
    await ctx.send('cooldown')
  elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
    await ctx.send('invoke')
  else:
    await ctx.send('should not happen')

@bot.command
async def doError(ctx, type : int):
  if(type == 0):
    raise commands.MissingPermissions
  elif(type == 1):
    raise commands.BotMissingPermissions
  elif(type == 2):
    raise commands.CommandOnCooldown

bot.run(token)
```

This is my first time asking a Question here, so please let me know if you Need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command errors you're attempting to catch are intended to be raised before the callback for the command is executed (from checks, converters, etc).  Exceptions raised within the callback will be wrapped in a [`CommandInvokeError`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandInvokeError), so it's clear where they come from.

For example, you could have an error handler like

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.TooManyArguments):
    await ctx.send('too many arguments')
  elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
    await ctx.send('invoke')
  else:
    await ctx.send('should not happen')
```

and a command like

```
@bot.command
async def doError(ctx, type : int):
  raise commands.TooManyArguments
```

If you actually pass too many arguments to the command, then the command handling mechanisms will produce a `TooManyArguments` exception and pass it to the handler.  On the other hand, if *your callback* produces a `TooManyArguments` exception, then the commands machinery will take that exception, wrap it in a `CommandInvokeError`, and then pass that to the handler.

Comment: thanks a lot! so it is not possible to differentiate between `BotMissingPerms` and `MissingPerms` like this? and thanks for making my Question more readable

Comment: If those errors are being raised by checks, then your code will work.  (You'll note that both errors inherit from `CheckFailure`).  Otherwise, you can have something like `if isinstance(error, CommandInvokeError): error = error.original` at the beginning of your handler